# Metonyms in American football: the National Football League

Tags: metonyms

Wikipedia has a great definition of metonymy [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy), but I have a more specific question.  The biggest user of NFL metonyms appears to be Gregg Easterbrook, writer of the Tuesday Morning Quarterback at ESPN.COM.
Can I have a list of metonyms used in American Football, particularly the National Football League (NFL)?

Answer (score 2):

I can give you one. The *gridiron* refers to the playing field, and to football in a general sort of way as well.

> **gridiron**
>
> 2 a field for football, marked with regularly spaced parallel lines.
>   • the game of football : [as adj. ] the national gridiron season . [NOAD]

Also, the football itself is called *the pigskin*. (Note: it's almost never used with the indefinite article, so be careful about calling it *a* pigskin.)

Answer (score 0):

Canton: The Pro Football Hall of Fame. (The Hall of Fame is located in Canton, Ohio.)

1265: The Green Bay Packers Front Office and Executives (Stadium and exectutive are offices located at 1265 Lombardi Avenue in Green Bay.)

Jersey/A and Jersey/B: The New York Jets and the New York Giants (Both play in The Meadowlands, a stadium located in New Jersey, not New York.)

The Hoodie: [Bill Belichick](http://www.patriots.com/team/index.cfm?ac=coachbio&bio=506) (His typical attire on the sideline is a hooded sweatshirt.)